# How do i customize spreadsheet with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel

I am using spreadsheet gem 0.6.5.7 for generating Excel file. I want to set the worksheet name as i desire. Currently the worksheet name is as 'worksheet1'. I want to customize the name according to the type of report generated. can anyone help me to solve this, as i am new to gem files. Or else we have any other gem which will be easy for customizing according to our need.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "to_xls" gem?

http://rubygems.org/gems/to_xls

there is even a gem exspecially for rails:

http://rubygems.org/gems/to_xls-rails

...

I didn't work much with xls files, but maybe it helps.

Comment: Nope. I will try this Hisako. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Customizing the name of your generated worksheet is actually a easy task. It can be done in the same Spreadsheet gem itself. (version 0.6.5.7).
Just we have to follow the below syntax.

```
book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new                       /* book is the workbook that gonna generated*/
sheet = book.create_worksheet :name=>"Project Report"  /* sheet is the worksheet which contain your data.*/
```

Hope this will be useful.
Thanks.